# When handeling a line's onAeraTouched using andengine I get a MethodNotSupportedException

Tags: android, exception, event-handling, line, andengine

I am writing an application that uses andengine to layout a representation of a room. I am trying to draw a wall by just drawing a line and allowing the user to rotate and move the line into position. I can draw the line and give the line an onAreaTouch listener. I registered the onAreaTouch using

```
scene.registerTouchArea(line);
```

When I run the application, I am able to draw the line. When I go to grab the line and move it the application crashes and gives a MethodNotSupportedException as shown below

**Logcat Error:**

```
04-16 10:51:41.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5048): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
04-16 10:51:41.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5048): org.andengine.util.exception.MethodNotSupportedException
04-16 10:51:41.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5048):     at org.andengine.entity.primitive.Line.contains(Line.java:242)
04-16 10:51:41.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5048):     at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onSceneTouchEvent(Scene.java:371)
04-16 10:51:41.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5048):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTouchScene(Engine.java:452)
04-16 10:51:41.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5048):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTouchEvent(Engine.java:438)
04-16 10:51:41.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5048):     at org.andengine.input.touch.controller.BaseTouchController$TouchEventRunnablePoolItem.run(BaseTouchController.java:102)
04-16 10:51:41.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5048):     at org.andengine.util.adt.pool.RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.onHandlePoolItem(RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.java:54)
04-16 10:51:41.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5048):     at org.andengine.util.adt.pool.RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.onHandlePoolItem(RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.java:1)
04-16 10:51:41.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5048):     at org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler.onUpdate(PoolUpdateHandler.java:88)
04-16 10:51:41.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5048):     at org.andengine.input.touch.controller.BaseTouchController.onUpdate(BaseTouchController.java:62)
04-16 10:51:41.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5048):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:584)
04-16 10:51:41.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5048):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:548)
04-16 10:51:41.584: E/AndroidRuntime(5048):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)
```

In the following code when I touch the line I should get "Line Touched!!!!", but I get the MethodNotSupportedException error.

**My Code For The Line**

```
@Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene,
        final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
switch (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
        case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            prevX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
            prevY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
            break;
        case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            currentX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
            currentY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
            break;
        case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Line line = new Line(prevX, prevY, currentX, currentY, WALL_WIDTH,
                    getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
                boolean mWallGrabbed = false;

                @Override
                public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                        float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "Line Touched!!!!");

                    return true;
                }
            };
            mScene.registerTouchArea(line);
            mScene.attachChild(line);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        return true;
 }
```

I have looked online for a solution, but it seems like nobody has done this before. There is nothing I could find that could solve this issue. Please let me know if there is a solution for this. If there no solution is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: I don't know the actual reason here, but it looks to me that onAreaTouched is unsupported on a line. You can try a rectangle instead, it's basically the same if you set the height/width correctly.

Comment: I am trying to use rectangles right now. The only problem is it is hard to draw anything not vertical or horizontal. It is just odd that Line doesn't support onAreaTouched.